# $ apt-get install git , this command is not running

Tags: 14.04, execute-command

[It gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9spW.png)

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will install the git package.

Comment: This command installs the package. OPs issue is that he runs this command yet gets an error. Reffer to the  linked duplicate for the proper solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two reasons :

1. You didn't use sudo
2. Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center is working

Please check and re try, thanks